# Do final fields really prevent mutability in Java?

Tags: java, immutability

From the famous book [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) chapter 3.4.1 **Final fields**

> Just as it is a good practice to make all fields private unless they
>   need greater visibility[EJ Item 12] , it is a good practice to make
>   all fields final unless they need to be mutable.

*My understanding of final references in Java* : A final reference/ field just prevents the the field from getting re initialized but if it references a mutable object , we can still change its state rendering it mutable . So I am having difficulty understanding the above quote . What do you think ?

Comment: You're conflating the *field* being mutable, and the *object* the field refers to being mutable. The value of the `final` field in and of itself cannot be changed, the state of the object it points to can. (This might be part of the rationale why they're called `final` and not `const`, to avoid confusion with the C++ feature that can enforce stronger restrictions.)

Comment: here is an explanation of the keyword final http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.at/2011/12/final-variable-method-class-java.html with examples.

Comment: @Geek The question between the lines? How about you spell it out instead. All I said is that a *field* and the *object* it points to are **different things**. The quote only says that `final` makes the *fields* immutable. It doesn't say anything about the *objects*, thus is makes sense.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

final fields prevent you from changing the field itself (by making it "point" to some other instance), but if the field is a reference to a mutable object, nothing will stop you from doing this:

```
public void someFunction (final Person p) {
    p = new Person("mickey","mouse"); //cant do this - its final
    p.setFirstName("donald");
    p.setLastName("duck");
}
```

the reference p above is immutable, but the actual Person pointed to by the reference is mutable.
you can, of course, make class Person an immutable class, like so:

```
public class Person {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    //getters and other methods here
}
```

such classes once created, cannot be modified in any way.

Answer (score 4):

This quote says only what is says:

> make all fields final unless they need to be mutable

*mutable field* is a field that you can later change to point to another object. If the field is `final`, it can still reference mutable object (e.g. `java.util.Date`). Thus the field is immutable (always points to the same object), but this object is mutable.

Comment: @Thomasz Please quote the source of the quote . Effective Java ??

Comment: @Geek. Psst! See your own question, you may find what you're looking for there. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

in java final is similer to this:

`int *const p=&something   //constant pointer.in c++. you can't use this pointer to change something but that something can be changed with its own.`

in java final fields can't be changed but the object to who they refer may change by its own .
Ex. `'this'` is final you can't assign anything to `this` but you can assign to object to whom this refer.

From your Ques:

`it is a good practice to make all fields final unless they need to be mutable.`

to just avoid any modification(either logically or accidently) to original it's always good to make them final.

Comment: I know const in C++ and final in Java are not equivalent. I also know what final means for references. My question is regarding the wordings in the quote from JCIP.

Comment: i give you the reference to c++ so just make the difference much clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

As per Java code convention final variables are treated as constant and written in all Caps e.g.

```
private final int COUNT=10; // immutable -> cannot be changed
```

Making a collection reference variable final means only reference can not be changed but you can add, remove or change object inside collection. For example:

```
private final List Loans = new ArrayList();
list.add(“home loan”);  //valid
list.add("personal loan"); //valid
loans = new Vector();  //not valid
```

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/final-variable-method-class-java.html#ixzz2KP5juxm0

To answer your question: Yes, if you use them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard the quote. There's little to no benefit from making your code blotted with `final`'s every now and then. Author aimed for a good practice, but in large code-bases, seeing everything made final rather obscures the intent, making reading code harder and more obscure - and may give little to no benefit.

### Two approaches

Generally though, there are two schools. Choose yours:

1. AGAINST, unless really needed

One is NOT to use `final`, unless you REALLY want those reading the code you wrote to know that this field is special in some way and is not to be trifled with.

1. For, there's never a bad place to use final!

The other is enamored with `final` and wants it everywhere. It's less prevalent. [Renauld Waldura](http://renaud.waldura.com/doc/java/final-keyword.shtml) makes for an excellent propagator of the idea. Read his linked entry, titled **"Final word on final keyword"**, it's a good and in-depth read.

### May depend on Java you use

On my part I'd just want you to know that `final` changed, and doesn't ALWAYS mean unmutable, as you can read in [Heinz Kabutz' Java Specialist Newsletter](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue096.html). He takes you through how it worked in different Javas, feel free to take his code and check the Java you use.